# How can I edit the translation file from ftp

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I edit the translation file from ftp?

File :

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
i18n.translations = {
  en: {
    home: {
        qrUnread: 'QRCode Okunamadı',
        scanner: 'Scanner',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question are not very clear.

I guess that you want to translate the string.
To do that you need to add another language in your json.

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
i18n.translations = {
  en: {
    home: {
        qrUnread: 'QRCode Okunamadı',
        scanner: 'Scanner',
    },
  fr: {
    home: {
        qrUnread: 'QRCode impossible à lire',
        scanner: 'Scanner',
    }
  }
}
```